# Messagebox dialog without switching facility

Tags: c#

How to show messagebox dialog which will not allow user to switch to another window as long as that dialog is not closed like shutdown dialog in windows XP using VB.NET or C# windows application

Comment: Eh, you sure that is a good idea from a usability perspective? Users don't like it when you take their whole desktop away from them. Blocking your own application, fine. But *everything*?

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily prevent interaction with other applications even from a system-modal message box.

One option is to display a large transparent window behind your message box with the WS_EX_TOPMOST window style. That way it would appear that the other windows are interactive, but clicks would hit your transparent window instead.

You couldn't prevent Control+Alt+Delete though and you'd have to take extra steps to prevent Alt+Tab and such. Also other topmost windows could still compete for the top.

In other words, it's a pain to do and for good reason. As [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/07/21/10040699.aspx) would say, you may have the most awesome and important application in the world but if it were easy then all of the other applications that aren't as awesome and important as yours would be able to abuse it.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called a **system-modal dialog**. This is in contrast to the more typical application-modal dialog, which only prevents the user from doing anything else in *your application* until they dismiss the dialog. A system-modal dialog extends this prohibition to the *entire system* and prevents the user from doing anything else at all with their computer until they've dismissed your dialog.

This was possible under 16-bit Windows (versions 3.x and earlier), but **this functionality was removed when 32-bit Windows rolled onto the scene** (as far back as Windows 95 and NT 3.5). Presumably, there were some vaguely more technical reasons that this capability was now denied to application programmers, but its absence also meant the end to widespread abuse of this feature by developers who thought their application was the only important thing the user could *possibly* be doing on their computer. (Some of those "vaguely more technical reasons" are related to better support for multitasking and the obsolescence of the "one program—one focus" paradigm.)

Raymond Chen answers the question definitively in a [forum post made to this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsuidevelopment/thread/54e2490a-992d-4d46-8def-0dc4bb600fcd):

> Win32 doesn't have system modal dialogs any more. All dialogs are modal to their owner.

If you want to simulate such functionality now (and it's highly recommended that you *not* do so, because it wasn't good programming practice before, and it's particularly alien to users now), you'll have to rely on a hack. This means your solution won't be fool-proof and could be easily bypassed by a knowledgeable or experienced user.

My recommendation is to *seriously re-consider* your need to prevent the user from switching to another application while a dialog box is visible in your application. System-modal dialogs are a contradiction with today's modern multitasking environments, and there are only *extremely* limited circumstances where they make sense. Most of those circumstances are limited to the operating system (the shutdown dialog from your example, UAC prompts from Windows Vista/7), rather than individual applications. See if you can't settle for the expected and less user-hostile application modal dialog instead, which you can get easily in C# and VB.NET using the [`ShowDialog` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx).